# Can I use the example character names from the PHB for characters in a story I'm writing?

Tags: dnd-5e, intellectual-property

My problem is that I was in need of a nice-sounding name for a character during one DnD session, so I used one from the Player’s Handbook, since I thought that it’s not going to be an extremely important NPC. But yeah, I was wrong. Now it has a huge background, history etc. and I considered writing a story (maaaaybe a book if my determination won’t leave me) about that character.

The question is - do I have to change his name? If I had to guess, I’d say yes, but on the other hand, it would sound a bit weird for me aferwards. Can I maybe just add a silent ‘h’ or something?

As “example names” I meant the ones given in the elf, dwarf etc. section in PHB.

Comment: Are you running the game at home or at an organized event/FLGS? Is it a question about legality or conflicting names in published material?

Comment: It sounds like the drive of this question is: "I named my character after someone from the player's handbook. Now I want to write a book about them. Do I have to change their name in the book?" — is that right? Or are you asking if you need to change their name in your games or something?

Comment: If so, hopefully they did not choose the name "Drizzt"

Comment: If the answer to @Rubiksmoose's question is "yes", then the question would probably be better suited to https://writers.stackexchange.com than it is to here.

Comment: @Quentin The licensing and copyright practices/issues around RPG materials is something we're more expert in than writers.se, so it's on topic here, and likely even to get a better answer.

Comment: I think that this question needs a bit more detail regarding the content of the story that you intend to write. If you don't plan to use anything from the OGL, then you're in a very different position than if you do.

Answer (score 7):

### You would almost certainly be better off using a different name.

You are the only person to whom a change would sound "weird", since this is a new story you are publishing.

The danger in using a name from the PHB is that you have no record of its provenance. It could be just a name pulled from mythology or world culture, or it could be a name used by a published character of greater or lesser prominence. The only way to be sure would be to hire someone qualified to do a copyright/trademark search to prove due diligence.

IP rule of thumb: when in doubt, don't. If you must, consult an expert. Don't cross your fingers and hope or take the advice of random answerers online as final (including mine).

Comment: + many for last paragraph =)

Answer (score 3):

### You cannot, without licensing the character.

The only license under which you can freely distribute 5e content is the OGL:

> Permission to  copy, modify and distribute the files   collectively    known   as  the System  Reference   Document    5.0 (“SRD5”)    is  granted solely  through the  use    of  the Open    Gaming  License,    Version 1.0a.

You cannot use any "Product Identity" under the OGL without specific licensing:

> 7. Use of  Product Identity:   You agree   not to  Use any  Product    Identity,   including   as  an  indication  as  to   compatibility, except  as  expressly licensed  in   another,   independent Agreement   with    the owner   of  each    element of  that    Product Identity.

...And "Product Identity" encompasses character names (emphasis added):

> **"Product Identity"   means** product and  product    line    names,  logos   and identifying marks including trade   dress;  artifacts;  creatures   characters; stories,    storylines, plots,  thematic    elements,   dialogue,   incidents,  language,   artwork,    symbols,    designs,    depictions, likenesses, formats,    poses,  concepts,   themes  and graphic,    photographic and    other   visual or   audio   representations;    **names and descriptions    of  characters**,   spells, enchantments,   personalities, teams,   personas,   likenesses  and special abilities; places,  locations,  environments,   creatures, equipment,   magical or  supernatural    abilities   or effects, logos,  symbols,    or  graphic designs...

...

> **The  following   items   are designated  Product Identity,** as  defined in  Section 1(e)    of  the Open    Game    License Version 1.0a,   and are subject to  the conditions  set forth   in  Section 7   of  the OGL,    and are not Open    Content:    Dungeons    &   Dragons,    D&D,    Player’s Handbook,  Dungeon Master, Monster Manual, d20 System, Wizards of  the Coast,  d20 (when   used    as  a   trademark), Forgotten   Realms, Faerûn, **proper    names   (including  those   used    in  the names   of  spells  or  items)**,   places,

If you're just pulling names from the suggested names in the races section, the infringement might be minor enough that nobody will care. You might even be able to claim that it was a coincidence, since many of those are just generic fantasy jumbles anyway. However, there's no explicit exception for those names, so you're still technically violating the OGL.

Comment: I don't think this applies to the example names in the Race chapter. Especially since some of them are clearly copied from other and older non-WotC content. (And aren't "characters" either, just names.)

Comment: @Erik that's true, and I doubt that Wizards could/would claim copyright on something like "Thorin," but those names are still proper names in the PHB and thus technically fall under the license.

Comment: Sounds like Blizzard, George R.R. Martin, H. P. Lovecraft, Square Enix, and countless religions are all in violation of this license. Either that or a general license that encompasses lists of names you print in a book doesn't hold any weight.